# Example for conditional Poisson regression

Tags: r, conditional-probability, poisson-regression

I am working with the dataset below, I am trying to predict the chances of

```
p(Stress|Snoring=1, Sleep=1), 
p(BMI|Snoring=1, Sleep=1), 
p(Caffeine|Snoring=1, Sleep=1)
```

I am assuming this is can be solved using conditional Poisson regression model, if yes I need help understanding conditional Poisson regression model or an example preferably using R.

```
Snoring Stress  BMI caffeine    Sleep   Freq
0       0       0       0       1       2886
1       0       0       0       1       714
0       1       0       0       1       0
1       1       0       0       1       0
0       0       1       0       1       0
1       0       1       0       1       0
0       1       1       0       1       0
1       1       1       0       1       0
0       0       0       1       1       42
1       0       0       1       1       0
0       1       0       1       1       0
1       1       0       1       1       0
0       0       1       1       1       0
1       0       1       1       1       0
0       1       1       1       1       0
1       1       1       1       1       0
0       0       0       0       0       0
1       0       0       0       0       0
0       1       0       0       0       10
1       1       0       0       0       51
0       0       1       0       0       10
1       0       1       0       0       38
0       1       1       0       0       12
1       1       1       0       0       142
0       0       0       1       0       0
1       0       0       1       0       42
0       1       0       1       0       9
1       1       0       1       0       37
0       0       1       1       0       14
1       0       1       1       0       63
0       1       1       1       0       5
1       1       1       1       0       133
```

Comment: In what sense do you intend "conditional" there? Is this distinct from the usual [Poisson regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_regression) (which is conditional in the sense that we're estimating $E(Y|X=x)$) or is the adjective simply meant to emphasize that Poisson regression is conditional in that sense? e.g. Did you perhaps mean conditional in the sense used [here](http://www.biomedcentral.com/1471-2288/14/122) ("*conditioning on the total event count in each stratum*") ?

Comment: @Glen_b, I updated my question now based on your feedback

Comment: If your responses are 0/1 why are you using Poisson regression?

Comment: @Glen_b, so conditional LR ?

Comment: Assuming I've understood the situation, and what you're trying to do, that would have been my first instinct, yes.

Comment: @Glen_b alright Glen that will work.

Comment: @Glen_b Or conditional probit regression, or conditional complimentary log-log regression. Binomial link functions gonna link! ;)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the discussion in the comments make it clear the problem was solved.